# How to quit R script when one R package not installed successfully?

Tags: r, try-catch, install.packages

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
install.packages("Deriv")
install.packages("vegan")
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mirt/mirt_1.27.1.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Above script is used to install packages.

How to make this script stop running (or quit) if anyone package is not installed successfully (warnings do not matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check installed packages after every install and use `stop` to stop the script with a meaningful message. E.g.

```
install.packages("Deriv")

if (!"Deriv" %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"]) {
  stop("Package Deriv not installed successfully.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
if (
  !all(
    c('Deriv', 'vegan', 'mirt') %in% installed.packages()
  )
) q()
```

Comment: I would test if package is installed after every call to `install.packages` because that's the spec OP wants. Call to `q()` really isn't necessary.

Comment: I would use `stop("meaningful message")` and within the `if` statement. @kittygirl